# Can i use multiple computers to run different programs with the same desktop environment?

Tags: remote-desktop, cluster

Is it possible to connect a laptop to a desktop computer in a way that i can run programs on the laptop and see them with barely any lag on my desktop computer? I'm not looking for a separate remote desktop, more a seamless integration that is responsive. So basically i want my laptop to run a program and see it on my desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

No. in absence of some other technology for sharing the output of a program, the program will execute on the CPU that spawned it exclusively.

you can:

1. remotely execute the program with a tool like SysInternals psexec
   (the -i switch apparently allows the session to interact with the
   desktop session per the documentation). that way you can run psexec on the
   laptop, but the executable it spawns will execute on the desktop and
   output to the desktops screen (only).
2. use a network output viewer like VNC or ssh with X forwarding.
   probably your best bet, and on a fast connection, shouldn't produce
   undue lag.
3. use a network application that runs on a server, which both the
   laptop and desktop can connect to. this of course requires an
   application be designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention OS, so I will  make some assumptions:

1) If using Linux / Xorg-based system, your safest bet will be with VNC, but that creates a full desktop experience

2) If using Windows, you might want to look at RemoteApp - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844(v=WS.10).aspx which covers the basics. I don't know much about the requirements (I think it requires the TS role, therefore it requires a Windows Server host). Citrix offers a similar solution (XenApp), but both these solutions are aimed at the enterprise.

If you require more help, please make your question more clear and provide details.